# Why parameters pass wrong registry Windows

Tags: windows, registry

I registred protocol in registry Windows

REGEDIT4

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc]
@="URL:VNC Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\RealVNC\\VNC Viewer\\vncviewer.exe" "%1"
```

Then. I try to run

[image]

But programm run not correct

[image]

Instead of addresses, it adds the word vnc. How can I remove this word?

Comment: Try `"%1:~4"` in your command handler

Comment: @burhan-khalid Not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because VNCViewer doesn't understand "vnc:192.168.4.107" as a valid argument.

You need to create a custom handler which removes the `vnc:` and passes the rest of the string to the executable.

Thankfully, someone [already did this](https://forum.ultravnc.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29030) on the UltraVNC forums:

```
ECHO OFF
SET S=%1
SET S=###%S%###
SET S=%S:"###=%
SET S=%S:###"=%
SET S=%S:###=%
SET S=%S:vnc:=%
start "VNCViewer" "C:\Program Files\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe" -connect %S%
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 someone on the UltraVNC forum provided a solution that works without an additional batch file:
https://forum.ultravnc.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29030#p107566

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc]
@="URL:VNC Protocol"
"URL Protocol"="http://www.uvnc.com/"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\DefaultIcon]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell\open\command]
@="cmd.exe /V /C \"set URL=%1& start \"\" \"C:\\Program Files\\uvnc bvba\\UltraVNC\\vncviewer.exe\" !URL:*://=!\""
```